# Xcode15 & iOS17 can not be debugged

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode15, ios17

When Xcode15 finish building App ,Xcode will stop  the running scheme automatically but app  keep running well,  so that I can’t debug the app.

Building some of apps  has such a problems only in Xcode15 & iOS17.

Does anyone have a solution？